# Bundling wysiwyg text editor jquery plugin with webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, wysihtml5

I'm working with a legacy jquery/bootstrap webapp, which I'm turning into a node.js / webpack project.
I was able to get most of it working, but for one element, the wysiwyg text editor.

Originally the project used [this editor](https://github.com/xing/wysihtml5), but it's no longer maintained and I couldn't get it to npm install from github anyway. This is when I started to google-fu for a drop-in replacement, and found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap3-wysihtml5-commonjs).

It needed handlebars and rangy in the global namespace, but this was not the end of it.
No matter what I tried so far, I can't get past the error:

```
vendor.bundle.js:13993 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
```

and the offending line reads:

```
$.fn.wysihtml5
```

This is what I don't understand, since jquery is in the global namespace, how come it's 'undefined'?

```
var App = function() {

    var uiInit = function() {

        $('.textarea-editor').wysihtml5();

    };

    return {
        init: function() {
            uiInit();
        }

    };
}();

$(function(){ App.init(); });
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "wysihtml-problem",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "fbielejec",
  "license": "LGPL",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
        "handlebars": "^4.0.5",
        "rangy": "^1.3.0",
    "bootstrap3-wysihtml5-commonjs": "0.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.7.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {

  entry: {
    app: "./app.js",
    vendor: ["jquery", "rangy", "wysihtml5"],
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      handlebars: 'handlebars/dist/handlebars.min.js',
      rangy: "rangy/lib/rangy-core.js",
      wysihtml5: "bootstrap3-wysihtml5-commonjs",
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: "wysihtml-webpack"
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(chunkName = "vendor", filename = "vendor.bundle.js"),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      'window.jQuery': "jquery",
      rangy: "rangy",
    })
  ]

};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jQuery tries to introspect the environment and doesn't pollute global namespace if it sees environment has a module system (and it finds one from Webpack).

Use this code to acquire a reference to jQuery object:

```
var $ = require('jquery')
```

You can also manually assign `$` on `window`:

```
window.$ = require('jQuery')
```

but using the first option is more preferred as it leads to more maintainable code and allows further optimisations (for example webpack which modules use jQuery and split bundle into several chunks accordingly).

Comment: Than you for looking into this, but to be honest I don't think this is the problem - after all $ is already pointing to 'my' version of jquery (the webpack 'vendor' bundle). To confirm I required $ like you say in the app.js entry point and the problem persists.

Comment: Yep, sorry, it looks like I didn't read the question entirely. Can put console.log into jQuery sources and just before the location of error. It looks like editor code is executed before jQuery.